# Rails console/rake detect in initializer. defined?(Rails::Console) does not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pry

I have an initializer in my rails app which I don't want to be started with rails console or rake task.

I put this code into my initializer:

```
puts "start"
if defined?(Rails::Console)
  puts "console"
elsif File.basename($0) == "rake"
  puts "rake"
end
puts "end"
```

When I run 'rails console' I get this:

```
$ rails console
start
end
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0.beta2)
[1] pry(main)>
```

But inside console:

```
[1] pry(main)> defined?(Rails::Console)
=> "constant"
```

However, it works for rake:

```
$ bundle exec rake routes     
start
rake
end
```

Why it works inside console, but doesn't in initializer? 
Or is there a better way to determine console/rake inside initializer?

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Comment: Thank you, Jan, for a clue. Yes, I'm using spring (as it's enabled by default) and when I turn it off I get expected behavior

Comment: No problem, maybe solution can be by adding a new environment RAILS_ENV=console bundle exec rails console..

Comment: Not is the better alternative but, using `File.basename($PROGRAM_NAME).split(' ').first == 'spring'` works.